# Several errors in Swift 3 Project

Tags: ios, swift

The four errors I get are

1: `Use of undeclared type 'MemeImage' - Line 46`

2: `Binary Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type '()' and 'Int' - Line 85`

3: `Unexpected non-void return value in void function - Line 113`

4: `Use of local variable 'makeMemedImage' before its declaration - Line 169`

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // Top of the storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var topBar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var shareBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

    // Middle of the storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var topTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomTextField: UITextField!

    // Bottom of the storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomBar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var albumBtn: UIBarButtonItem!


    // text attributes
    let topTextDefault = "TOP TEXT"
    let bottomTextDefault = "BOTTOM TEXT"
    let noText = ""

    let topTextDelegate = TopTextDelegate()
    let bottomTextDelegate = BottomTextDelegate()

    // meme attributes
    let memeTextAttributes:[String: Any] = [NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.black, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont( name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40 )!, NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: NSNumber( value: -4.0 )]

    var isKeyboardVisible = false

    // Use of undeclared type 'MemeImage'
    var meme: MemeImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        cameraBtn.isEnabled = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.subscribeToKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    func initTextFields(textField: UITextField, initialText: String, delegate: UITextFieldDelegate) {

        textField.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
        textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        textField.text = initialText
        textField.delegate = delegate

    }

    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
        if bottomTextField.isFirstResponder {

            // Binary Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of ttype '()' and 'Int' -----------
            view.frame.origin.y = getKeyboardHeight(notification) * -1


        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {
        if bottomTextField.isFirstResponder {
            view.frame.origin.y = 0.0
        }
    }

    func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil )

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil )
    }

    func unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver( self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil )
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver( self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil )
    }

    func getKeyboardHeight(_ notification:Notification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue

        // Unexpected non-void return value in void function---------
        return keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height

    }

    func imagePickCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imageWasPicked(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                imageView.image = image
                shareBtn.isEnabled = true
                cancelBtn.isEnabled = true

        } else {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func pickImageType(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) {

        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.sourceType = sourceType

        self.present( pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func getImageFromCamera(_ sender: Any) {

        pickImageType(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)

    }

    @IBAction func getImageFromAlbum(_ sender: Any) {

        pickImageType(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary)

    }

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {

        shareBtn.isEnabled = false
        imageView.image = nil
        topTextField.text = topTextDefault
        bottomTextField.text = bottomTextDefault

        meme = nil

    }

    @IBAction func share(_ sender: Any) {

        // Use of local variable 'makeMemedImage' before its declaration ------------
        let memedImage = makeMemedImage()
        let socialController = UIActivityViewController( activityItems: [memedImage], applicationActivities: nil )
        socialController.completionWithItemsHandler = {

            UIActivityType, completion, items, error in

            if completion {

                self.saveMemedImage(memedImage: memedImage) {
                }
                } else {
                    self.dismiss( animated: true, completion: nil )
                }
            self.present(socialController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

        func makeMemedImage() -> UIImage {

            topBar.isHidden = true
            bottomBar.isHidden = true

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
            view.drawHierarchy( in: self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true )
            let memedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            topBar.isHidden = false
            bottomBar.isHidden = false

            return memedImage
        }

        func save() {
            self.meme = memedImage.init(topText: self.txtTop.text!, bottomText: self.txtBottom.text!, origImage: self.imgView.image!, memedImage: memedImage)

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to search past questions for any of these commonly encounter error messages?

Comment: Yes, I've been trying for a few days, I was 15 error's and have brought it down to four. Haven't been able to see what mistakes I've made with them.

Comment: Please search on errors before posting. Your error #3 is obvious. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Unexpected+non-void+return+value+in+void+function

Comment: and please add comments where the linenumbers are. here in stackoverflow there is nor line counting

Answer (score 0):

mostly the error messages are self explaining...

> 1: Use of undeclared type 'MemeImage'

there is no class MemeImage in your project (maybe typo?)

> 2: Binary Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type '()' and 'Int'

the function is returning nothing, thats why you can not use a `*` here (fixed with answer 3)

> 3: Unexpected non-void return value in void function

the function declaration don't have a return value declared

```
func getKeyboardHeight(_ notification:Notification) {
```

change to `Int` or whatever you return here:

```
func getKeyboardHeight(_ notification:Notification) -> Int {
```

> 4: Use of local variable 'makeMemedImage' before its declaration

i see that the function `makeMemedImage` is on the wrong level

**Solution A** (not recommented - but that resolves exact the error message)

if you like to have it as a function inside `@IBAction func share(_ sender: Any) {` then you need to move this block bevor the first usage

**Solution B** (recommented - better coding style, only when you need it for a very special case then inline a function)

change the nesting level of the function `func makeMemedImage` (and the other `func save`) to be outside of `@IBAction func share`. move an `}` from the line after `func save { ... }` to a line before func makeMemedImage`)

Answer (score 0):

I just pasted it into a playground and the errors popped right up.  My guess is this code was copy and pasted from some source with little attempt into actually fixing it, i.e., not even all the brackets pair up (error #4).

1. Means exactly what it says.  It cannot find a class called `MemeImage` anywhere in your project.  Does that class exist?
2. `getKeyboardHeight` is a function that doesn't declare it's return type (which is also your reason for error #3).  So you're trying to multiply by a function.
3. See #2
4. You're missing a closing `}` between the `share` function and the `makeMemedImage` function.